# How to use the new `git switch` to go to a commit?

Tags: git

I'm starting to learn git and the recommendation was to use `git switch` instead of `git checkout`. I know how to get to a parent commit using checkout:

`git checkout HEAD~3`

But when using switch like this:

`git switch HEAD~3`

I get the following error

`fatal: a branch is expected, got commit 'HEAD~3'`

Comment: i guess it will work if you add `-d` to specify that you want to be in `detached HEAD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git switch` is stricter about what it operates on than `git checkout`. Whereas `git checkout` will create a detached `HEAD` if you try to check out something that is not a branch head, `git switch` will not, *unless* you explicitly signal your intent to do so by using the `-d`/`--detach` option.

```
git switch -d HEAD~3
```